# Android Kotlin: Integration testing if the current activity or app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, integration-testing, ui-testing

I am working on an Android Kotlin project. I am writing integration/ UI tests for my application using the Expresso test framework. I am trying to write a test for a scenario where my application is closed or the first/ main activity currently open is closed. But it is not working.

See my test code below.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class EventListTest: TestBuilder()
{
    @get:Rule
    val eventListActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<EventListActivity> = ActivityTestRule<EventListActivity>(EventListActivity::class.java, true, false)

    @Test
    fun itFinishesActivityWhenLogoutMenuItemIsTapped() {
        FakeEventService.SCENARIO_UNDER_TEST = 0
        this.eventListActivityRule.launchActivity(null)
        Intents.init()
        openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>())
        onView(withText(eventListActivityRule.activity.resources.getString(R.string.menu_item_logout))).perform(click())

        intended(not(hasComponent(EventListActivity::class.java.name)))
        Intents.release()
    }

}
```

Basically, I am testing that it closes the current activity when the log out menu item is clicked. Since the current activity (EventListActiivty) is the only open activity, it will finish the app. In the activity class, it closes itself using finish() method. But when I run the test, I got the following error.

```
W/example.mement: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/Activity;->mResultCode:I (light greylist, reflection)
W/example.mement: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/Activity;->mResultData:Landroid/content/Intent; (light greylist, reflection)
E/TestRunner: failed: itFinishesActivityWhenLogoutMenuItemIsTapped(com.example.memento.EventListTest)
E/TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

    IntentMatcher: not has component: has component with: class name: is "com.example.memento.EventListActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

    Matched intents:[]

    Recorded intents:[]
        at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
        at androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:80)
        at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:346)
        at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$3.run(Intents.java:204)
        at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$PropogatingRunnable.run(Intents.java:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2163)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
I/TestRunner: finished: itFinishesActivityWhenLogoutMenuItemIsTapped(com.example.memento.EventListTest)
```

How can I test this scenario and how can I fix my code?

I also used this.

```
Assert.assertTrue(eventListActivityRule.activity.isDestroyed)
```

But it is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. Here it is.

```
Assert.assertTrue(eventListActivityRule.activity.isFinishing)
```

It is similar to testing the action bar back button pressed event.